# can't transform dates (str) into numeric format

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to run this code inorder to extract the promotion periods in terms of days by substracting two columns in my data frame which are "promo_end_dt" and "promo_start_dt". Each of these two columns have the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

```py
#promotions period

from datetime import date as dt

transactions['promo_start_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(promos['promo_start_dt'])
transactions['promo_end_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(promos['promo_end_dt'])

#promos['promos_period'] = promos['promo_end_dt'].sub(promos['promo_start_dt'],axis=0)
promos['promos_period'] = (promos['promo_end_dt'] - promos['promo_start_dt']).dt.days
#promos
```

however I keep getting this error message :

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py in na_op(x, y)
>       967         try:
>   --> 968             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
>       969         except TypeError:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
>       220     if use_numexpr:
>   --> 221         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
>       222     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
>       126     if result is None:
>   --> 127         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
>       128
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
>        69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
>   ---> 70         return op(a, b)
>        71
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         8 
>         9 #promos['promos_period'] = promos['promo_end_dt'].sub(promos['promo_start_dt'],axis=0)
>   ---> 10 promos['promos_period'] = (promos['promo_end_dt'] - promos['promo_start_dt']).dt.days
>        11 #promos
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)
>      1046 
>      1047         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
>   -> 1048             result = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
>      1049         return construct_result(
>      1050             left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name, dtype=None
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py in na_op(x, y)
>       968             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
>       969         except TypeError:
>   --> 970             result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
>       971 
>       972         return missing.dispatch_fill_zeros(op, x, y, result)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
>       445         if mask.any():
>       446             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
>   --> 447                 result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], com.values_from_object(yrav[mask]))
>       448 
>       449     else:
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: You are changing the to datetime in `transactions` dataframe and then calling the operation in `promos` dataframe.

Comment: :O make sense ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
promos['promos_period'] = (promos['promo_end_dt'] - promos['promo_start_dt']).dt.days
```

Should be:

```
promos['promos_period'] = (transactions['promo_end_dt'] - transactions['promo_start_dt']).dt.days
```